# ffmpeg - how to merge multiple audio with time offset into a video

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -y -i earth.mp4 -i 1.wav -i 2.wav -i 3.wav -filter_complex "[1]adelay=delays=5s:all=1[r1]; [2]adelay=delays=8000S:all=1[r2]; [3]adelay=delays=15s:all=1[r3]; [r1][r2][r3]amix=inputs=3[a]"  -map 0:v -map "[a]" -codec:v copy output.mp4
```

I am using the above code but getting an error in ubuntu 20.04.1

Error is => `Error initializing filter 'adelay' with args 'delays=1s:all=1'`

Comment: Update ffmpeg to 4.4

Comment: how to update can you provide the cli command for updating ffmpeg for ubantu 20.04.1

Comment: @AndrewsGilbert Download from [johnvansickle.com](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/), see [FAQ](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/faq/) for install instructions. Or follow [FFmpeg Ubuntu compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).